# Angular2 datepicker 403 error

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I have problem with my angular2 application. Im trying to add datepickers to my "date" fields. I installed ng2-datepicker, i have it in my node_modules, but when im trying to start application i have error 
:

> :3276/node_modules/ng2-datepicker/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

My systemjs.config file:

```
 paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',

        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
        'underscore': 'npm:underscore@1.8.3',
        'moment': 'node_modules/moment',
        'file-saver': 'node_modules/file-saver',
        'ipa.datePickerService': 'node_modules',
        'ng2-datepicker': 'node_modules/ng2-datepicker',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        moment: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'ng2-datepicker': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
```

i really dont know whats going on with it.. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for a 403 in your case would be that you are trying to load a directory when the server has directory browsing disabled, for example if you mean to load...

```
/node_modules/library/app.js
```

But you only pass the folder, not the file...

```
/node_modules/library/
```

If there is a specific file to load, add that and it should work.

The second most common problem would be that the resource is genuinely access-controlled and your user isn't allowed to access it... but I think you have the first problem.

Comment: I tried to change it in systemjsconfig to:   'ng2-datepicker': 'node_modules/ng2-datepicker/index.js', but i have this error still..